# How to decrypt raw soap response encrypted with x509

Tags: c#, web-services, encryption, x509, wse

We have a batch program that talks with a third party providers web service with WSE, the call to the WSE webservice is encrypted with a x509 certificate.

We have two different certificates to the third party provider

1. Pre-Production Certificate
2. Production Certificate

We have implemented a `WebServiceResponseLogger`  that inherits from `SoapInputFilter`, this is added to the `Pipeline` as an `InputFilter`. this does a fine job logging the response when using the pre-production certificate. However when we switch to Production and utilize the production certificate, the response is not logged.

Now we have seen the request and response trough fiddler, so we know that a response actually appears, the problem is that the response we can see in fiddler is the raw response.

I've tried googling trying to figure out if we could decrypt the response in fiddler, we have the correct certificates, so I'd figure it would be possible. and if not with fiddler, does a Tool already exist that would allow me to decrypt the soap response?

Comment: I don't think you will find a tool for that as this will help with man-in-the-middle attacks, even that you have the certificate. Perhaps you can explain better your problem. What you mean by 'it is not logging?'.

Comment: We have an inputfilter that logs request and response, the envolope.OuterXML property gets stored in our local database for both the request and the response, but the data stored in the response is just NULL, it seems as if the inputfilter is never actually hit when we use the production certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got around to posting the solution i found, in case someone else runs into this problem :)

I managed to find a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529137.aspx) on MSDN that put me on the right track and constructed the following console program that sucessfully decrypted the response I had from our fiddler sessions.

I installed the WSE 2.0 NuGet package

```
try
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529137.aspx
    XmlDocument response = new XmlDocument();
    response.Load("Response.xml");
    var encryptedKeyElement = response.GetElementsByTagName("xenc:EncryptedKey")[0] as XmlElement;
    var encryptedDataElement = response.GetElementsByTagName("xenc:EncryptedData")[0] as XmlElement;

    EncryptedKey encryptedKey = new EncryptedKey(encryptedKeyElement);
    EncryptedData data = new EncryptedData(encryptedDataElement, encryptedKey);

    var decryptedData = data.Decrypt();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: so frustrating that msdn that the example does not come up.